# Example of non-trivial functors

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

In Haskell, functors can almost always be derived, is there any case where a type is a functor and satisfies functor laws (such as `fmap id == id`) but cannot be derived according to a simple set of rules?

And what about Foldable, Traversable, Semigroup and others? Is there any non-trivial cases available?

Comment: You mean something like tuple when you don't know should you apply function to first value or second?

Comment: @talex No, if you treat a tuple of (a, b) as a functor over b, then the result of fmap is (a, c), from which it's very clear which value shoud the function b -> c be applied to.

Comment: Agree. Now I'm curious too.

Comment: Functor in Haskell can always be derived. Bartosz Milewski talks about this in his book *Category Theory for Programmers*[1]. I need to look up the exact reference and details myself but it has to do with functors in Haskell forming some sort of an algebra. 

[1] https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/

Comment: @michid I believe functors can always be derived. I'm curious of whether this is also true for other type classes generally? For example, if I do proof search as in dependently typed languages such as Idris, the result of fmap of Functor List can also be [], but it does not confirm to the fmap id law, and haskell does not have a deriving mechanism that check laws.

Comment: Foldable, Traversable, and Semigroup all have symmetries which allow them to be lawfully instantiated in multiple distinct ways, which is one sense of nontriviality at least

Comment: @luqui, if you use an Atkey-style indexed applicative to define a notion of traversable for type-aligned collections, then you should recover uniqueness.

Answer (score 13):

Here's kind of a fun argument I just stumbled on.  (It's late so I wonder if it will be sensical tomorrow)

We can construct the type of proofs of [SK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) reducibility as a GADT:

```
infixl 9 :%:
data Term = S | K | Term :%: Term

-- small step, you can get from t to t' in one step
data Red1 t t' where
    Red1S :: Red1 (S :%: x :%: y :%: z) (x :%: z :%: (y :%: z))
    ...
```

Now let's make a type which hides its functorhood at the end of a reduction chain.

```
data Red t a where
    RedStep :: Red1 t t' -> Red t' a -> Red t a
    RedK    :: a                     -> Red K a
    RedS    :: (a -> Bool)           -> Red S a
```

Now `Red t` is a `Functor` if `t` normalizes to `K`, but not if it normalizes to `S` -- an undecidable problem.  So perhaps you can still follow a "simple set of rules", but if you allow GADTs, the rules have to be powerful enough to compute anything.

(There is an alternative formulation which I find rather elegant, but maybe less demonstrative: if you drop the `RedK` constructor, then `Red t` is a `Functor` if and only if the type system can express that the reduction of `t` *diverges* -- and sometimes it diverges but you can't prove it, and my mind boggles about whether it's really a functor in that case or not)

Comment: Why might it not be a functor if reduction diverges? If you choose a deterministic reduction strategy in `Red1`, define `data Blue t where BlueStep :: Red1 t t' -> Blue t' -> Blue t`. (For a non-deterministic strategy, things get kind of ugly, because you have to separate out all the overlapping rules). Now you can consume `Red t a` alongside `Blue t`. At each step, the `Red1 t t'` in the `Blue t` proves that `t` is not `S`.

Comment: @dfeuer, hm I'm not sure I'm following.  Sure we can get that `t` is not `S` at each step, but in order to prove functorhood we need that at *every* step

Comment: I haven't *quite* gotten there, but [this gist](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/a381c329ce740ae911bc62539eb8bb51) sets up the framework I sketched, and goes much of the way toward expressing a proof of divergence for a particular example.

Answer (score 10):

Explicitly empty parametric types can be made into functors automatically:

```
data T a deriving Functor
```

However, implicitly empty ones can not:

```
import Data.Void
data T a = K a (a -> Void)
    deriving Functor  -- fails
{-
error:
    • Can't make a derived instance of ‘Functor T’:
        Constructor ‘K’ must not use the type variable in a function argument
    • In the data declaration for ‘T’
-}
```

However,

```
instance Functor T where
   fmap f (K x y) = absurd (y x)
```

is arguably a legal instance.

One could argue that, exploiting bottoms, one can find a counterexample to the functor laws for the instance above. In such case, however, I wonder if all the "standard" functor instances are actually lawful, even in the presence of bottoms. (Maybe they are?)

Comment: Most of the usual `Functor` instances are valid even with bottoms, I believe. Here's a simple type GHC can't derive `Functor` for: `data Foo a = Foo (a -> Bool) !Void`. There's another way contravariance can get in the way: `newtype Bar f a = Bar (f a -> Bool)`. GHC can't derive the perfectly valid instance
`instance Contravariant f => Functor (Bar f) where fmap f (Bar g) = Bar (g . contramap f)`. The main trouble is that adding `Contravariant` into the deriving mix leads to be multiple potential instances (with incompatible constraints) for things like `newtype Baz f g a = Baz (f (g a))`.

Answer (score 8):

There are no non-trivial functors in the sense of the question. All functors can be derived mechanically as sums (`Either`) and products (`Tuple`) of the `Identity` and the `Const` functor. See the section about [Functorial Algebraic Data Types](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/02/03/functoriality/) for how this construction works in detail.

On a higher level of abstraction this works because Haskell's type form a [Cartesian Closed Category](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/03/13/function-types/) where terminal objects, all products and all exponentials exist.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit cheaty, but here we go. According to [this](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/commentary/compiler/derive-functor) then functor cannot be derived automatically when there's a constraint on the type, eg.

```
data A a where
    A1 :: (Ord a) => a -> A a
deriving instance Functor A -- doesn't work
```

and indeed, if (say) we wrote a manual version, it wouldn't work either.

```
instance Functor A where
    fmap f (A1 a) = A1 (f a) -- Can't deduce Ord for f a
```

However, because all the algorithm's doing is checking that no constraint exists, we can introduce a typeclass of which every type is a member.

```
class C c
instance C c
```

Now proceeding as above with `C` instead of `Ord`,

```
data B b where
    B1 :: (C b) => b -> B b

deriving instance Functor B -- doesn't work

instance Functor B where
    fmap f (B1 b) = B1 (f b) -- does work!
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard type in `base` called `Compose` defined like this:

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
```

The derived `Functor` instance is implemented this way:

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose v) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) v)
```

But there is another perfectly lawful instance with different behavior:

```
instance (Contravariant f, Contravariant g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose v) = Compose (contramap (contramap f) v)
```

To me, the fact that two distinct instances are available for `Compose` suggests to me that no set of rules can be automatically applied to cover all possible cases.

Comment: Where both sets of constraints hold (i.e., when both `f` and `g` have phantom parameters), the instances have the same behavior. So I'd say this is about incompatible constraints rather than different behaviors.